# Subring of any Boolean ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Kindly help me in this one.

Is Z/2Z always a subring of any non-zero Boolean ring with identity?

I think it is not true always. Let X be a non-empty set. P(X) be the set of all subsets of X. Then P(X) is a Boolean ring with the binary operations symmetric difference and intersection of sets. Z/2Z is not subset of any non-empty set X, also the binary operations are different. 
But I am not sure about my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ always a subring of any non-zero Boolean ring with identity means that ring contains isomorphic copy of this $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ as a subring. In your case $\{\phi, X\}$ is a copy of $\mathbb{Z/2Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Any boolean ring $R$ with identity $1$ contains a copy of $F_2$, namely $\{0,1\}$, as a unital subring.

If you don't care whether or not your copy of $F_2$ shares identity with $R$, then *any* nonzero element $x$ is going to produce a copy $\{0,x\}$ of $F_2$.

Comment: The actual question is like below.                                          Let R be any non-zero boolean ring with identity. Can we say Z/2Z is a subring of R?

Comment: Every boolean ring does not have the same identity. Hence please explain.

Comment: If your boolean ring $R$ has identity $1$, then $\{0,1\}\subseteq R$ is a copy of $F_2$. What is your question about this?

Comment: I was able to reword to make my answer a little more concise.

Comment: @rschwieb: I think the issue is rather the difference between equality and isomorphism.  Of course, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is usually not _equal_ to a subring of $R$, just isomorphic.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: Please give me some reference books for your answer. I want to challenge this question in a competitive exam and they need some references.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rschwieb: Suggest me some reference books

Comment: @DEBASISSHARMA I cannot think of any references that would bother stating this fact: it's too trivial. Are you sure we've got the question statement correct? It seems unlikely a triviality like this would be overlooked, so it seems there is a great chance that it is not what was intended. Are the questions posted online?